# Knockout.js data-bind array to list of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox, knockout.js

```
Patient 1
    Patient.Age = '25'
    Patient.Injury[0].Date = '2015-01-01'
    Patient.Injury[0].Type = 'Burned'
    Patient.Injury[1].Date = '2015-01-27'
    Patient.Injury[1].Type = 'Sprained Ankle'

Patient 2
    Patient.Age = '17'
    Patient.Injury[0].Date = '2015-01-08'
    Patient.Injury[0].Type = 'Papercut'

<!-- ko foreach: Patient -->
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: ?"> Sprained Ankle
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: ?"> Burned
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: ?"> Papercut
<!-- /ko -->
```

Looping through an array of multiple patients and displaying a list of checkboxes of injury types of each patient. How do I select multiple checkboxes per patient, based off of sub-array of injuries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you somewhere should have a list of all possible injuries let say that will be in a parent view model (along to collection of patients) and called `AllInjuries` also you will need to add some method to your `Patient` class what will iterate through all patient's injuries and will determine if that patient has that injury, let say it called `hasInjury`. Then you will be able to use something like this:

```
<!-- ko foreach: Patient -->
    <!-- ko foreach: $parents[1].AllInjuries -->
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.hasInjury($data.Type)">
        <span data-bind="text: Type"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```